# Form Validation empty field shown as invalid in Angular 2+

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am trying to do some Form Validations on my form using reactive form validation. However, I run into some issues when checking a field that is touched and dirty.

Brief Example:

HTML:

```
<input id="name" class="form-control"
      formControlName="name" required >

<div *ngIf="name.invalid && (name.dirty || name.touched)"
    class="alert alert-danger">

  <div *ngIf="name.errors.required">
    Percent is required.
  </div>

  <div *ngIf="name.invalid">
    Number must be between 0 and 1
  </div>

</div>
```

Typescript:

```
name: ['', [Validators.min(0.0001),Validators.max(0.9999),Validators.required]],
```

So my form logic is correct. If I enter a number not between 0 and 1, I get only one return that says Number must be between 0 and 1. However, the problem lies when I click the field and then click out. I get both errors that "Number is required" AND "Number must be between 0 and 1". How would I structure my logic so that only the error message "Number is required" displays?

Comment: instead of `name.invalid` use `<div *ngIf="name.errors.max || name.errors.min">`

Comment: also it's good to use `Validators.Compose([Validators.min(0.0001),Validators.max(0.9999),Validators.required])` for multiple validators

Comment: I changed it to <div *ngIf="name.errors.max || name.errors.min"> and it worked! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can  I post this as answer ? Can you accept it?

Comment: posted as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a small mistake in your `*ngIf` condition as you are using `name.invalid` which is always true for any kind of error. That's why you are seeing both messages at the same time.

instead of `name.invalid` change it to like below -

```
<input id="name" class="form-control"
      formControlName="name" required >

<div *ngIf="name.invalid && (name.dirty || name.touched)"
    class="alert alert-danger">

  <div *ngIf="name.errors.required">
    Percent is required.
  </div>

  <div *ngIf="name.errors.max || name.errors.min">
    Number must be between 0 and 1
  </div>

</div>
```

Now it will only show the message `Number must be between 0 and 1` if the entered value is not between 0 and 1.